# The query string on Grails application's URL is not URL enoded

Tags: java, url, grails, unicode, groovy

My Grails version is 2.4.3
My Java is 1.7
The platform my Grails runs is Windows 8.1
I build a Grails application. The below is my Controller

```
class BoxController {
    def index() {
        println params.id
        println params.mykey
        render "OK"
    }
}
```

I type this URL on my browser :

```
http://localhost:8080/myweb/box/index/中文?mykey=中文
```

In Eclipse Console, I saw below:

```
中文
����
```

But if I URL encode my Chinese word first and then put it back on my URL which is:

```
http://localhost:8080/myweb/box/index/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87?mykey=%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87
```

Then I see the result on Eclipse console is:

```
中文
中文
```

This result is correct and is what I want. 
The most wired thing is that if I run my Grails application/Eclipse in Linux (Ubuntu 14.04), even my URL is not URLEncoded, the result in Eclipse console on Ubuntu is correct.

Due to some reason, it is impossible to do URLEncode on my URL first, so my problem is, how to let Grails know that my query string is not URL encoded and don't do any convert so that my BoxController can get correct content from params.mykey on Windows 8.1 ?

Thank you for your help.